# How to create installer files in Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, pi-2, rpi.gpio

I have created a program in Raspberry pi and I am running it using the command *python myprogram.py* . Is it possible to create the installer file of this program? that means after installing this program(app) the user should able to start the program(app) by clicking on the icon from desktop or selecting from the start menu.